# How to return all users

Tags: angular, symfony

I wan't displaying `all users` in my `admin page`. 
I don't found and i don't know the `function symfony` to `return all users` in `angular`. Would you know the code please? 
I use a db, with mysql and phpmyadmin

I know the problem comes from my symfony function. I would like the function that returns all the user listed backoffice

My function in UserController.php :

```
/**
 * @Rest\Get("/allUsers")
 */
public function getAllUsers()
{
    // TODO: récupérer tout les utilisateurs de la base de donnée.
    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getDoctrine()->getUser();;

    return new Response($user);
}
```

My userService.ts :

```
getAllUsers() {
 return this.api.get('api/user/allUsers');
}
```

I use `Angular 7` and `Symfony 4`

I return the current user whit that function in my UserController.php

```
public function getUser()
{
    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    $response = $this->serializer->serialize($user, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('user.get')));

    return new Response($response);
}
```

Comment: Does your `getAllUsers` of the `UserController.php` work? If the problem is in the Angular part, could you explain what is `this.api`?

Comment: For me the problem comes from the symfony function. I'm using a REST API, and instead of "this.http" I make the link with "this.api"

Comment: Could you try calling your API directly with Postman for example?

Comment: I have a 500 error, so I think my error comes from the symfony function
Mais je cherche et je n'ai trouvé nul pars la function qui retourne tout les users

Comment: We need more information about you backend code to help you to solve your problem.

Comment: I have edited my post

Answer (score 0):

[Simple API](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/03/08/simple-rest-api-php)

call that api Using Angular HTTPClient

```
// this.http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").
//     subscribe((data) ⇒ console.log(data))

this.http.get("this is your servie URL ").
          subscribe((data) ⇒ console.log(data))
```

Comment: I misspoke. I would like to recover users of the database

Comment: mens you want to get users from db? then what db?

Comment: I use WAMP server, so I use mysql.
I have entity user with firstname, lastname, etc... and i have create 4 user with my register form

Comment: first create simple php service

Comment: with that function, i have 10 user

Answer (score -1):

you didn't provide your app component but i assume you have not  made a method that gets your data from the service. ill share one of my Methods for getting a data from a service.

If you use an Http request (you use Rest API) so :

this is how your service should look :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Container } from '../Container';



  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class MarinServiceService {

    Marinurl : string = 'http://192.168.0.83/MarinApi/api/Values';
    constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }


    public getAllContainers():Observable<Container[]>{
      return this.http.get<Container[]>(this.Marinurl)
    }
}
```

Change the Method name and Object according to your names.

And here is the Component Method :

```
users  = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.marinService.getAllContainers().subscribe((result)=>{
    this.users = result;
```

Change it according to your names.

Basically you need to subscribe to your method -> think of it like a viewer subscribing to a YouTube channel. and the keeps looking for new videos.

Comment: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForFor' since it isn't a known property of 'li'. ("

Comment: @Benji49 you have an extra **For** and use astrix => * before the ngFor.

Comment: I wrote this <li *ngFor="let users for users">
I don't understand why I have an error

Comment: <li *ngFor="let user  **of** users" li> and did you mange to get results from the API you can check that from the natwork Tab in your chrome if you use chrome.

Comment: I have "500 Internal Server Error" ... 
The problem would not come from the function in symfony ?

Comment: Internal error is from your symfoni as it’s a server error